# How to Change the data type of a cloumn(schema) using aws athena through query

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have uploaded my data and started the crawler but now i want to change the datatype of one perticular column in the glue crawler for example cloumn 1. name its datatype is string and 2. day its datatype is double now i want to change the day datatype to string is it possible through query or is their any option to change or update the column data type through glue api. Their is option to change datatype in glue console but i want to know how to change using aws athena or apis of glue. See i have refered this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/types-of-updates.html#updates-changing-column-type but it gives me error.
[FAILED: ParseException line 1:6 missing EOF at '-' near 'my' ]

Comment: This really depends on your use-case, but if you're unhappy with glue's type deduction, maybe you can try to define the table manually?
This can be effective when: 1) data is a very deeply nested json and you don't want to coerce type for every negligible key (that may not exist), in which case you simply define all the data as csv and then parse it as you please when querying. 2) when your schema is rather small and predefined.
I'm writing this since my experience with glue wasn't good and I ended up enjoying the above solution much more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.